# How to compare two char in Latex

Tags: xstring, compare

I need to compare two char (or string), but I can't:

could you help me, please!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen}

\begin{document}
\def\cero{\StrMid{01}{1}{1}}
\def\uno{\StrMid{01}{2}{2}}

\def\word{101010101}
\def\bit{\StrMid{\word}{5}{5}}


this is cero: \cero \\
this is one: \uno


this is the word: \word \\
this is the 5th bit: \bit

.... but I cant't compare them!!

\ifthenelse{\equal{\bit}{\uno}}
    {this is 1}
    {this is 0}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `\def\bit{\StrMid{\word}{5}{5}}`, the macro `\bit` is *not* either 0 or 1, but it's the instructions for *printing* either 0 or 1.

You should use the optional argument to `\StrMid` (common to several `xstrings` functions):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen}

\begin{document}
\StrMid{01}{1}{1}[\cero]
\StrMid{01}{2}{2}[\uno]

\def\word{101010101}
\StrMid{\word}{5}{5}[\bit]

this is cero: \cero

this is one: \uno

this is the word: \word

this is the 5th bit: \bit

\ifthenelse{\equal{\bit}{\uno}}
    {this is 1}
    {this is 0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `expl3`'s string range function

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \midstr \str_range:nnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Midstr \str_range:Nnn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\def\cero{\midstr{01}{1}{1}}
\def\uno{\midstr{01}{2}{2}}

\def\word{101010101}
\def\bit{\Midstr{\word}{5}{5}}


this is cero: \cero \\
this is one: \uno


this is the word: \word \\
this is the 5th bit: \bit

.... but I cant't compare them!!

\ifthenelse{\equal{\bit}{\uno}}
    {this is 1}
    {this is 0}

\end{document}
```

Note that this uses 'real' TeX strings (*i.e.* the results from `\midstr`/`\Mistr`  are tokens of category code 12 only, except for spaces which are catcode 10).